# onFormat string For NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, format-string

I want to sort data with "id" key, how can I understand what is format string for `NSPredicate` format ? I have an 100 number post.
My code :

```
 let objectIDs = posts.map{$0.id}
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self IN %@", objectIDs)
    let sortByUserId = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
```

I have an error with this description:

> can not parse "self IN %@" format string.

**Code for Parsing JSON Data:**

```
func postsFromJSONData(data : NSData, inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> PostResult {
            do{
            let jsonObject : [[String:AnyObject]]
            = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

            for postJSON in jsonObject {
                if let post = postFromJsonObject(postJSON, incontext : context) {

                        finalPost.append(post)
                    }
                }

            return .Sucsess(finalPost)
            }
            catch let error {
                return .Failure(error)
            }

        }
```

fetch the main queue posts when the web service finishes:

```
func fetchRecentPost(completion completion: (PostResult) -> Void){

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: recentPostURL(["":""]))

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error)  in

    var result = self.processRecentPostRequest(data: data, error: error)

    if case let .Sucsess(posts) = result {

        let mainQueueContext = self.coreDataStack.mainQueueContext
        mainQueueContext.performBlockAndWait(){

            try! mainQueueContext.obtainPermanentIDsForObjects(posts)
        }

        let objectIDs = posts.map{$0.id}
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self IN %@", objectIDs)
        let sortByUserId = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)

        do{
            try self.coreDataStack.saveChanges()
            let mainQueuePosts = try self.fetchMainQueuePosts(predicate: predicate, sortDiscriptors: [sortByUserId])
            result = .Sucsess(mainQueuePosts)
        }
        catch let error {

            result = .Failure(error)
        }
    }

        completion(result)

        })
```

Comment: show your data that you want to sort!

Comment: Your question is not clear, if you want just sort array you can do like this. `var sortedPosts = posts.sort({ $0.id < $1.id })`

Comment: I am trying parse this JSON and save posts data in core data http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/

Comment: Then show us the code that you have write for parsing and core data saving. Also your json array is already sorted by id in ascending order.

Comment: Your core data attribute is also `id`?

Comment: (There is a typo in `.Sucsess` ...)

Comment: No, core data attributes are title, id, userId,body,and postID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicte should be like this

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", objectIDs)
let sortByUserId = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
```

**Note :**  It is either `self.id IN %@` or `id IN %@`.

Comment: Do I need to not sort my data ? any time my application running my data add to last saved data in data base file, why this happen?

Comment: If your data is not in order than sort it, Are you getting data now using predicate?

Comment: my JSON is sorted with userID, Yes I,m get data but when any time application launch data again, and again add to data base , my post in data base now more than 1000.

Comment: You mean duplicate record is added?

Comment: Yes, when i am clear store and launch application first time my post count is 100 , and when stop application and launch again data up to 200, whats happening?

Comment: May be every time you open it will storing data in core data that is the reason you are getting 200 data.