# Using predicate to fetch records which their id's are in an array in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

idList is an array of Int.
I want to fetch records which their id is in this array
For instance: idList = [1,2,10] then three records with id 1, 2 and 10 are fetched.
I am sure that these record exist but the output of executeFetchRequest is empty. And its correct for other queries.

```
lets predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id= %@", "\(idList)")
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Post")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
mainQueuePosts = try mainQueueContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Post]
```

I also tried this:

```
lets predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", "\(idList)")
```

both didn't work.

Comment: @NiravD I checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/39546576/7442920 but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: What you are doing is converting array to string you need to make predicate like `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", idList)` Don't write like `"\(idList)"` because this will make array as string

Comment: @NiravD Thanks It solved the problem